# find the volume of region above triangle and below surface

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Find the volume of the given solid, under the surface $z=xy$ and above the triangle with vertices $(1,1), (4,1)$ and $(1,2)$.

so I tried taking the double integral $$\int_1^4 \int_1^{-1/3(x+7/3)} xy \,dy \,dx$$

(i got the first $y$ equation from the slope intercept form equation)

But I got around 18 and the answer was $\frac{31}8=3.875$. Am I setting this up right? I'm afraid theres some misconception I have about this type of problem. If someone could help It would be greatly appreciated. I followed similar examples and they lead me to this setup, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the equation connecting the point $(1,2)$ and $(4,1)$ again.

Suppose the equation that you find is $y=-\frac13(x+c)$

The corresponding integral should be

$$\int_1^4 \int_1^{-\frac13(x+c)} xy \, dy \, dx$$

Comment: i meant to write the −1/3(x+7/3) on the bottom. and is that equation wrong? I'm not understanding why.

Comment: substitute  $x=4$ in $-\frac13(x+\frac73)$ and check whether you get $1$?

Comment: not 1... oh snap.. I was not supposed to put the parentheses around the 7/3. so I guess if the upper bound to the integral was -1/3 x + 7/3 it would be right?

Comment: yes, that seems to be correct.